# How to save the model weights after running train_detector in mmdetection?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, google-colaboratory, object-detection

```
cfg.optimizer.lr = 0.02 / 8
cfg.lr_config.warmup = None
cfg.log_config.interval = 600
# Change the evaluation metric since we use customized dataset.
cfg.evaluation.metric = 'bbox'
# We can set the evaluation interval to reduce the evaluation times
cfg.evaluation.interval = 3
# We can set the checkpoint saving interval to reduce the storage cost
cfg.checkpoint_config.interval = 3
# Set seed thus the results are more reproducible
cfg.seed = 0
set_random_seed(0, deterministic=False)
cfg.gpu_ids = range(1)

cfg.load_from = 'gdrive/My Drive/mmdetection/checkpoints/vfnet_r50_fpn_mdconv_c3- 
c5_mstrain_2x_coco_20201027pth-6879c318.pth'
cfg.work_dir = "../vinbig"
cfg.runner.max_epochs = 6
cfg.total_epochs = 6model = build_detector(cfg.model)
datasets = [build_dataset(cfg.data.train)]
train_detector(model, datasets[0], cfg, distributed=False, validate=True)
```

Now,my question is once I have finetuned the model on my custom dataset,how do i use it for testing? Where is the finetuned model stored?
At most of the places, the model is immediately used for testing but how do I save the finetuned model to be tested later on.

```
img = mmcv.imread('kitti_tiny/training/image_2/000068.jpeg')

model.cfg = cfg
result = inference_detector(model, img)
show_result_pyplot(model, img, result)
```

The above is what occurs mostly after the training phase. But that is because the model is already in runtime.How can i create my own mmdetection model checkpoint?
I have been working on Google colab.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know how to do it manually, but your checkpoints are automatically
saved in `cfg.work_dir = "../vinbig"`. There you can find `'latest.pth'` file as your final checkpoint.

Comment: Yeah,thank you. This I did find a few days ago.But now I have another query.While building the model(inference detector stage),what will be the config file parameters?.Like in init_detector(),the config file I pass -should that have the same parameters as the ones I had set during training stage?(the parametes like cfg.load_from,cfg.work_dir and all those).Do i change them during testing stage or do i use the same config file?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to find, because the documentation in [mmdet.core.evaluation.eval_hooks](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection/blob/master/mmdet/core/evaluation/eval_hooks.py) is not very clear, but the old version at  [their readthedocs](https://mmdetection.readthedocs.io/en/v2.9.0/_modules/mmdet/core/evaluation/eval_hooks.html) describes a  `save_best` attribute to the `EvalHook`

```
save_best (str, optional): If a metric is specified, it would measure
        the best checkpoint during evaluation. The information about best
        checkpoint would be save in best.json.
        Options are the evaluation metrics to the test dataset. e.g.,
        ``bbox_mAP``, ``segm_mAP`` for bbox detection and instance
        segmentation. ``AR@100`` for proposal recall. If ``save_best`` is
        ``auto``, the first key will be used. The interval of
        ``CheckpointHook`` should device EvalHook. Default: None.
```

To enable it, you can just add the argument to the `evaluation` attribute in the config:

```
cfg.evaluation = dict(interval= 2, metric='mAP', save_best='mAP')
```

This will test the model on the validation set every 2 epochs and save the checkpoint that obtained the best *mAP* metric (in your case it might need to be `bbox` instead), in addition to every checkpoint indicated by the `checkpoint_config.interval` attribute.

:)

Edit: mmdet's `EvalHook` inherits from mmcv's [`EvalHook`](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmcv/blob/6254ebef8d1d106e9cca8d4097786c6172cf70ce/mmcv/runner/hooks/evaluation.py#L17), where the documentation is complete.